# `Members` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm getting a foreign key error.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Members;
CREATE TABLE Members (
    memberID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    lastName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    joinDate DATE NOT NULL,
    birthday DATE NOT NULL,
    membershipID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    trainerID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY(membershipID) REFERENCES Memberships(membershipID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(trainerID) REFERENCES Trainers(trainerID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Trainers;
CREATE TABLE Trainers (
    trainerID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    firstName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    specialization VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(trainerID)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Memberships;
CREATE TABLE Memberships (
    membershipID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    price DECIMAL(19,2) NOT NULL,
    details VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(membershipID)
);
```

I've tried changed the keys.  I've made sure the keys and attributes are the same.  I feel like the foreign keys are styled corrected in the Members tables.

Answer (score 2):

It's just about ordering the table creation scripts. By reordering the table creation scripts so that `Memberships` and `Trainers` are created before the `Members` table, you ensure that the referenced tables exist when defining foreign key constraints in the Members table. This should resolve the foreign key constraint error you're encountering. Here is the sql script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Trainers;
CREATE TABLE Trainers (
    trainerID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    firstName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    specialization VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(trainerID)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Memberships;
CREATE TABLE Memberships (
    membershipID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    price DECIMAL(19,2) NOT NULL,
    details VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(membershipID)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Members;
CREATE TABLE Members (
    memberID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    lastName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    joinDate DATE NOT NULL,
    birthday DATE NOT NULL,
    membershipID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    trainerID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY(membershipID) REFERENCES Memberships(membershipID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(trainerID) REFERENCES Trainers(trainerID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

You can check on [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sBReRfko)